# Average two arrays with different underlying x-scales in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, average

I have two different x vs y data sets in Python, where x is wavelength and y is flux. Example:

```
import numpy as np
wv_arr_1 = np.array([5564.0641521, 5566.43488632, ..., 8401.83301412])
flux_arr_1 = np.array([2.7731672e-15, 2.7822637e-15, ..., 8.0981220e-16])

wv_arr_2 = np.array([5109.3259116, 5111.34467782, ..., 7529.82661321])
flux_arr_2 = np.array([2.6537110e-15, 3.7101513e-15, ..., 2.9433518e-15])
```

where `...` represents many additional numbers in between, and the arrays might not necessarily be the same lengths. I would like to essentially average my two data sets (the flux values), which would be easy if the wavelength scales were exactly the same. But since they're not, I'm unsure of the best way to approach this. I want to end up with one wavelength array and one flux array that encapsulates the average of my two data sets, but of course the values can only be averaged at the same (or close enough) wavelengths. What is a Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: You need to explain to people what you mean by exact same scale and “Values can only be averaged at the same wavelengths “

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit open-ended from a scientific point of view. What you want to do only makes *complete* sense if the two datasets should correspond to the same underlying function *almost exactly*, so that noise is negligible.

Anyway, the first thing you can do is map both of your datasets to a common wavelength array. For this you need to [interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) both sets of data on a 1d grid of wavelengths of your choosing. Again if the data is too noisy then interpolation won't make much sense. But if the datasets are smooth then you can get away even with [linear interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html). Once you have both datasets interpolated onto a common wavelength grid, you can trivially take their average. Note that this will only work if the sampling density is large enough that any larger features in the spectra are well-mapped by both individual datasets.

If your data is too noisy perhaps the only reasonable thing you can do is to take the *union* of the datasets, and [fit a function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) from an educated guess onto the joint spectrum. For this you will have to have a very good idea of what your data should look like, but I don't think there's a general-purpose solution that can help you in this case, not without introducing uncontrolled artifacts into your data.